# Elm Autocomplete On User Input

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, user-input, elm

I'm very new to Elm. I have an input field on a webpage. When the user types in the input field, I would like to query a list of words (which are stored in initialModel) and give completion suggestions based on what is typed in the input field. I think I need Html.Events for the keypresses, so I have already imported it. I know I also need an update function, so I've included and empty function. Here is the code I have so far. Thanks in advance.

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)

import StartApp.Simple as StartApp

-- MODEL

type alias Model =
  {
    words: List String
  }

initialModel : Model
initialModel =
  {
    words =
      [ "chair", "sofa", "table", "stove", "cabinet", "tv", "rug", "radio", "stereo" ]
  }


-- UPDATE
update =
  {

  }


-- VIEW

title : String -> Html
title message =
  message
    |> Html.text


pageHeader : Html
pageHeader =
  h1
    [  ]
    [ title "Hello" ]


pageFooter : Html
pageFooter =
  footer
    [  ]
    [ a [ href "#" ]
        [ text "Hello" ]
    ]

inputField : Html
inputField =
  input
    [ type' "text" ]
    [ ]


view : Html
view =
  div
    [ id "container" ]
    [ pageHeader
      , inputField
      , pageFooter
    ]

-- BRING MODEL, VIEW AND UPDATE TOGETHER

main =
  view
  -- StartApp.start
  --   {
  --     model = initialModel
  --     , view = view
  --     , update = update
  --   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Model needs to keep track of the current value of the textbox. You can start off with creating a `SetValue` action that updates model.value during the `update` function:

```elm
type alias Model =
  { value : String
  , words : List String
  }

initialModel : Model
initialModel =
  { value = ""
  , words =
      [ "chair", "sofa", "table", "stove", "cabinet", "tv", "rug", "radio", "stereo" ]
  }

type Action
  = SetValue String

update action model =
  case action of
    SetValue value ->
      { model | value = value }
```

You will also need to trigger the update function on input into that textbox. You can do this using the [`on` event attribute](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-html/4.0.2/Html-Events#on). It is common to listen to the *input* event, which gives you more information than individual key press events:

```elm
inputField : Address Action -> Html
inputField address =
  input
    [ type' "text"
    , on "input" targetValue (Signal.message address << SetValue)
    ]
    [ ]
```

Lastly, you'll need to display a div with the autocomplete contents:

```elm
autocomplete model =
  let
    matches =
      List.filter (startsWith model.value) model.words
  in
    div []
      [ div [] [ text <| "Autocomplete input: " ++ model.value ]
      , div [] [ text "Autocomplete matches: " ]
      , div [] <| List.map (\w -> div [] [ text w ]) matches
      ]
```

If you decide to get more complex and want an external source for autocompletion, you'll need to switch to [StartApp](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/start-app/2.0.2/) instead of StartApp.Simple because of its support for Effects and Tasks.

The code snippets above rely on a few other changes to what you originally posted, so I've posted a [gist with a working example](https://gist.github.com/freakingawesome/875fbad5d4f8c5f1d982) that you can plug into http://elm-lang.org/try. Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! One more question: how can I figure out which of your imports I have to add with elm package?

Comment: `evancz/start-app`, `evancz/elm-html`, and `evancz/elm-effects` should do it for you.

Comment: Yep, I figured it out. Well, actually, as soon as I compiled, it told me which one I was missing. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Here is @ChadGilbert Gist adapted for ELM v18: https://gist.github.com/fycth/3938d8969df5cd839ddb2ed8c3fd4b30